# winrt xaml merged resources

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, resourcedictionary, mergeddictionaries

I need to separate application styles to several xaml files.
But I also need to define some shared values like

```
<x:Double x:Key="SharedValue">100</x:Double>
```

in single file for use this value in styles defined in other files.
For instance:

```
<Style x:Name="SomeStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
     <Setter Property="Width" Value="{StaticResource SharedValue}"/>
</Style>
```

and in another resource dictionary file:

```
<Style x:Name="AnotherStyle" TargetType="Button">
     <Setter Property="Height" Value="{StaticResource SharedValue}"/>
</Style>
```

But when I try to define merged resource dictionary in App.xaml file

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary >
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="DefinedValues.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles1.xaml"/>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles2.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

I get this runtime exception:"Message = "Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key SharedValue"

Can you tell me is it posible to do this and what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Where are you seeing the message?  Are you trying to access the resource in XAML with {StaticResource} ?

Comment: I'm getting this error when it is handled in App.g.i.cs file as unhandled exception in runtime but intelisence don't light my SharedValue as unrecognized anywhere.

Comment: Yes, this is possible, and I was able to create an app using your example and it works on my project.  Are you sure you have the correct path to DefinedValues.xaml and the other two ResourceDictionaries in your App.xaml file?

Comment: Path was wright but I had several faults which I didn't know about. First one was I made mistake with order of declared dictionaries and the second was I didn't reference to the SharedValues dictionary in dependent ones. After I correct these mistakes everything works fine. Thanks, you helped me!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using merged dictionaries can get a bit tricky if you have dependencies between other merged dictionaries.

When you have multiple application-scope resources the order of the declare is important.  They are resolved in the inverse order of the declare, so in your case you should have the order.

```
<Application.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary >
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles1.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles2.xaml"/>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="DefinedValues.xaml"/>

    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Also, you may need to reference the other ResourceDictionary in Styles1.xaml.  This worked for me in Styles1.xaml.

```
<ResourceDictionary "...">

  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="SharedValues.xaml" />
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

  <Style x:Name="AnotherStyle"
         TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Height"
            Value="{StaticResource SharedValue}" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: FYI, when you get an acceptable answer, you can upvote the answer, but you should also "Accept" the answer.  That way your reputation on StackOverflow rises, and people are more likely to help you in the future.

Comment: The second part is the important one. The order of the files doesn't matter in my case, but register the style in my template really helped. Thx