# Any designer-friendly way to reference static resources inside class libraries without importing in every xaml file?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I am building a universal class library with Xaml Views that need to statically reference *custom* resources (StaticResource) defined inside the same class library.

How can i do that in a designer friendly way without importing the resource file inside every view?

Using VS2013 Update 3. It seems that the designer works only for views inside the specific universal app projects and when the resources are defined inside App.xaml without merging.

Comment: Whoa, every view? Haha nooooo! Are you saying something like [MergedDictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.resourcedictionary.mergeddictionaries(v=vs.110).aspx) didn't work for ya?

Comment: Yes it doesn't work. Designer still complains even if i directly merge the static resources inside every View let alone defining it on the App.xaml level.

Comment: Uh, yea, you shouldn't have to do all that mess, you should literally just be able to throw like ` <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/The.Project.blah;component/Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml"/></ResourceDictionary/></ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries> in your app.xaml at most.

Comment: Right. You'd think so. Like it works in WPF. Nope in WinRT-land though

Comment: Not just wpf, but silverlight, phone, etc, and even RT, you sure you got your paths right etc? Or maybe an issue like [this fella](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001421/winrt-xaml-merged-resources) had?